# How to download only subtitles of videos using youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

How can I download subtitles of a list of videos using youtube-dl? I need an option for this. However I could not find an option to download only subtitles

Comment: the option is --skip-download

Comment: Maybe because he already downloaded the videos, and doesn't want to download them again, just wants to download the subtitles now because he didn't get them before. That's why I'm using this option.

Comment: Or it messed up the `--embed-subtitles` step so I want to download them again separately.  (Iʼd file a bug report but the repoʼs down for the moment)

Comment: @Prometheus … Perhaps because YouTube subtitles are not in the standard .srt format, he got the YT timestamped formant, now wants .srt … I'm here because I have vids that have no subtitles, so I want to get them easily.

Comment: @HashimAziz Judging use-cases is not an answerer's job.

Comment: Good news, all these answers seem to work with the more updated `yt-dlp` as well FWIW...

Answer (score 298, accepted):

There is an option, [mentioned in the documention](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/#subtitle-options):

### Subtitle Options:

```
--write-sub                      Write subtitle file
--write-auto-sub                 Write automatic subtitle file (YouTube only)
--all-subs                       Download all the available subtitles of the video
--list-subs                      List all available subtitles for the video
--sub-format FORMAT              Subtitle format, accepts formats preference, for example: "srt" or "ass/srt/best"
--sub-lang LANGS                 Languages of the subtitles to download (optional) separated by commas, use IETF language tags like 'en,pt'
```

So for example, to list all subs for a video:

```
youtube-dl --list-subs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ye8mB6VsUHw
```

To download all subs, but not the video:

```
youtube-dl --all-subs --skip-download https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ye8mB6VsUHw
```

If a video only has auto generated subtitles, then `--all-subs` still won't download it, instead use:

```
youtube-dl --write-auto-sub --skip-download https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ye8mB6VsUHw
```

Comment: I gave the docs a fair look and didn't find the `--skip-download` option which is hidden under ***Verbosity / Simulation Options***. Glad @fivetech asked this question, or I may still be stuck.

Comment: how to download autogenerated subtitles?

Comment: It's clearly "mentioned in documentation" and "clearly mentioned in this answer": "--write-auto-sub Write automatic subtitle file (YouTube only)"

Comment: It's not that "clearly mentioned in documentation". What is the difference between write-sub, write-auto-sub vs all-subs?

Comment: @brauliobo `--write-auto-sub` from [documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/#subtitle-options), `youtube-dl --sub-lang LANG --write-auto-sub --skip-download URI`.

Comment: Trying to download subtitles at the moment gives `ERROR: '—list-subs' is not a valid URL. Set —default-search "ytsearch" (or run  youtube-dl "ytsearch:—list-subs" ) to search YouTube` message. I'm running youtube-dl v2019.02.08.

Comment: @user598527: There should be two dashes preceding the option, not one (`--list-subs`).

Comment: @l'L'l: Thank you, I've been using [an addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxreplace/) to convert `--` to `—` for some days, didn't cross my mind how it can affect code and commands. Thankfully I didn't create a bug report!

Comment: `youtube-dl --sub-lang en --write-auto-sub --sub-format srt --skip-download v0uYZ4rTOrk` 1. get ENG subtitles 2. get auto-generated subtitles 3. get subtitles in srt format 4. do not download the movie

Comment: It never would have occurred to me that `--skip-download` would still download things.  That is not clearly mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: [Alternative documentation link](https://github.com/github/dmca/tree/416da574ec0df3388f652e44f7fe71b1e3a4701f#subtitle-options) as the original was taken down by evil gremlins.

Comment: I want subs inserted in video (hardcoded): `--embed-subtitles` and `--write-sub` do the trick?

Comment: It should be made clear in the answer above that if the closed captions are auto generated they are NOT downloaded by `--all-subs`.  

You must use `--write-auto-sub` instead. 

I think this is a programming/implementation error on the part of youtube-dl, however it is such a great tool that I think we can hardly hold it against them.

Comment: `No subtitle format found matching "srt"` ?  Is it limited by what the server supports?

Comment: `yt-dlp` (see https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) seems to be way more up-to-date, well-maintained, and functional than `youtube-dl` today. It is a fork off of `youtube-dl`. So, if you're having trouble with this answer, try `yt-dlp` instead.

Answer (score 78):

Or you can only download one subtitle

```
youtube-dl --write-sub --sub-lang en --skip-download URL
```

Comment: Or `--write-auto-sub` for downloading the automatically generated subtitles!

Comment: @pouya will your option download both autogenerated and proper subtitles of english lang, for example?

Comment: The accepted answer is painfully lacking the required flag. This should be accepted answer.

Comment: `--all-subs` apparently implies a `--write-sub`...

Answer (score 29):

just run the following command

```
youtube-dl --write-auto-sub --convert-subs=srt --skip-download URL
```

For example you are downloading
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=example. with title "example"
`--convert=srt` will output to a file named `example.en.srt` where `en` stands for English `es` for Spanish etc.

The file will have something like this:

```
00:00:04.259 --> 00:00:05.259
&gt;&gt; I’m Elon Musk.

00:00:05.259 --> 00:00:06.669
&gt;&gt; What is your claim to fame?

00:00:06.669 --> 00:00:07.669
&gt;&gt; I’m the founder of

00:00:07.669 --> 00:00:08.669
Tesla.com.
```

OPTIONAL - If you need the text to be cleaned up you can use python to clean it a little:

```
import re
bad_words = ['-->','</c>'] 


with open('example.en.vtt') as oldfile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            newfile.write(line)


with open('newfile.txt') as result:
    uniqlines = set(result.readlines())
    with open('sub_out.txt', 'w') as rmdup:
        mylst = map(lambda each: each.strip("&gt;&gt;"), uniqlines)
        print(mylst)
        rmdup.writelines(set(mylst))
```

Output newfile.txt:

```
I’m Elon Musk.
What is your claim to fame?
I’m the founder of
Tesla.com.
```

Comment: Just as a markup from the doc: `--convert-subs FORMAT
              Convert the subtitles to other format (currently supported: srt|ass|vtt|lrc)`

Comment: convert subs doesn't seem to work if you use the --skip-download option it just gives it in vtt format

Comment: In my case, I still need to run `ffmpeg -i foo.vtt foo.srt` to convert caption manually.

Comment: python script does not work well...

Comment: The script works just fine. You need to run 'youtube-dl --write-auto-sub --convert-subs=srt --skip-download URL ' first.  Within the same folder run the script. Change bad_words = ['-->'] to  bad_words = ['-->','</c>'] since the format seem to have changed a little. hope this helps.

Comment: @pt123 not working open issue: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/9073

Comment: Please read the docs if you still have issues. https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#subtitle-options

Comment: After some testing, I can say that 1) `--convert-subs` switch doesn't work with the `--skip-download` one; 2) anyway `youtube-dl` uses `ffmpeg` (or `avconv` from the [dead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/7121513) Libav project) to do the subtitle conversion, so the `ffmpeg -i foo.vtt foo.srt` produces the equal srt file; 3) both `--convert-subs=srt` and `--convert-subs srt` options works.

Comment: `--convert-subs` seems to work for me with `yt-dlp` and `--skip-download` for what it's worth..

Answer (score 4):

Another simple way to download subtitles from YouTube is to download [Google2SRT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/google2srt/). Google2SRT is a free, open source program for Windows, Mac and Linux that is able to download, save and convert multiple subtitles from YouTube videos.

#### Usage

<sup>Click the links to see screenshots of steps 1 and 2.</sup>

1. [Paste the URL in the *Google subtitles* text box and click *Read*.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaFdj.png)
2. [Choose the language by selecting the appropriate check box provided and press *Go*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmsD2.png).
3. View the destination folder that was input in the *SRT subtitles* textbox to locate the SRT files.

Comment: The issue with this is that it only works with YouTube; youtube-dl supports hundreds of other sites.

Comment: The question is about youtube-dl.

Comment: Thanks so much, jegadesh! Google2SRT is just what I needed to download auto-generated closed captions/subtitles from YouTube, since youtube-dl does not handle them properly (instead returning _foo has no subtitles_).

Comment: @miles-wolbe I'd appreciate it if you could mention a YouTube video where youtube-dl failed.

Comment: @naki https://youtu.be/nv99gj1xxWw

Comment: @PhaniRithvij nope, `# youtube-dl --write-auto-sub --skip-download https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nv99gj1xxWw` works fine on `2021.04.17`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with URL like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C63moDmemSY ...

Comment: one advantage this has is that it's has zero alerts on VirusTotal  (of 61 virus programs) per 8 oktober 2023. Nitpicking: 10-11 programs can't check .MSI applications...   https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/93a89aaba675446c7c4aa3f8fdebfa0a63ad329316549d8485cbc8873a3d787c