# Automatically Copying Texts that are Inside a Video to a Microsoft Word document

Tags: youtube

I've seen Blackbox extension on chrome and I have a question about it. Have you guys seen those YouTube Vocabulary tutorials that is 4 hours long and contains over 2000 words with their meaning. Is there a way to copy all those vocabulary (and there meanings) to a Microsoft Word documents automatically in a very fast way without the need of watching the whole tutorial?

Comment: You could read documentation instead of relying onto a youtube video.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @mashuptwice the best thing about these videos is that they offer accurate pronunciation along with the word meaning. That's why they are very helpful. Unfortunately who made the video doesn't share any documentation. If you want to learn a new language you need an organized roadmap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download only subtitles of videos using youtube-dl](https://superuser.com/questions/927523/how-to-download-only-subtitles-of-videos-using-youtube-dl)

Comment: @Guest seems like I've missed the part about "vocabulary". The linked solution should be capable of that if the video contains correct subtitles.

Comment: @mashuptwice unfortunately the video doesn't contain any subtitles. It's interesting to see that there is something has not been programmed yet. Hope the programmers community find a solution about this in the future.

Comment: You still fail to give an example of such a video. Of course there are solutions for OCR, also examples of OCR on video files/streams. Most are purpose built systems. Simplest thing would be to download the video, run it through ffmpeg with the mpdecimate filter and output a bunch of PNGs, which can then be analyzed by tesseract. This will only work nicely with high-contrast text. I'll not explain how to do it in detail, there is enough documentation available.

Comment: Hello @mashuptwice Thank you for your help. This is an example "https://youtu.be/HrSXHs3LMlU". Would the solution you mentioned above do the trick ? Also, what exactly should I search for?

Comment: Just tested it with `tesseract` and it works fine, even with the white on blue text. Here are resources for implementing: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61843093/ffmpeg-how-to-extract-a-png-sequence-from-a-video-remove-duplicate-frames-in-t) [2](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)

Comment: Thank you I will test it and let you know. @mashuptwice